# How can I avoid repeating DocumentRoot in this Apache virtual host?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have an Apache virtual host configured for a website powered by Wordpress.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 67.178.132.253
DocumentRoot /home/david/wordpressWebsite

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond /home/david/wordpressWebsite%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

</VirtualHost>
```

How can I avoid hard-coding `/home/david/wordpressWebsite` twice? I don't want to use `REQUEST_URI` since that involves an extra request.

Here's my attempt at using a directory context. I made a file in sites-available with these contents.

```
DocumentRoot /home/david/wordpressWebsite

<Directory /home/david/wordpressWebsite>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
    # You need these somewhere, anyway; better to not put them on the root.
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

For some reason, Apache is seeking files in /var/www as evinced in my error logs:

```
[error] [client 69.175.67.64] File does not exist: /var/www/about, 
referer: http://67.178.132.253/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future people who stumble upon this and want an answer to the original question:
**How can I avoid repeating DocumentRoot in this Apache virtual host?**

The value of the **DocumentRoot** directive can be accessed by using the server variable
**%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}**. This means that in the OPs example, instead of writing:

```
RewriteCond /home/david/wordpressWebsite%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

We can write

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Therefore, the only place you should hard code your root file path is in the DocumentRoot directive.

Answer (score 2):

Those Wordpress rules were built to be inside a `<Directory>` context, as evidenced by the fact that they're looking for `^index\.php$` without a leading slash; that rule won't ever match in a `<VirtualHost>` context.

Once inside a `<Directory>` context, the `REQUEST_FILENAME` variable contains the physical file location, as explain in the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

> The full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request, if this has already been determined by the server at the time REQUEST_FILENAME is referenced. Otherwise, such as when used in virtual host context, the same value as REQUEST_URI.

So, try something like this:

```
<Directory /home/david/wordpressWebsite>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
    # You need these somewhere, anyway; better to not put them on the root.
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

As far as hard-coding it twice (in both the `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory>` settings): if you really need to avoid that for some reason, then look into the ["config file variables" feature of Apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/new_features_2_4.html).

Comment: Thank you! I posted a second attempt above using a directory context. For some reason, Apache now seeks files in /var/www.

Comment: @DavidFaux It's using the default site; you probably want to modify the default site file instead of creating a new one.